# Flash movie not loading after switch to CS4/Mac

Tags: flash, macos, cs3

We recently made the switch to CS4 on a Mac from CS3 on Windows. Now we are having issues getting our flash movies to load. We get the "Movie not loaded.." error. We are using swfobject. The same Flash file worked fine prior to editing with CS4 on the Mac.

Comment: I assume you mean not loading in a browser since you reference swfobject, but your post suggests you cannot open the fla file in cs3 windows...  could you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

It ended up being a permissions issue on the webserver. Although we were using root permissions on the webserver, apparently OS X was being stingy and permissions were not set correctly when we moved it.